# clear the filters added in `top`

Tags: top

In `top` I can press <kbd>o</kbd> to add filters. My question is how I can clear those filters.

I googled around and it is not easy to find an answer. From the help page, I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>O</kbd> can be used to display the active filters. There the prompt says press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to resume. No other option is provided, such as amending a filter or deleting a filter.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I guess you found this out already, but just for the sake of others running into this question when googling, pressing <kbd>=</kbd> should reset all filters added with <kbd>o</kbd> when running top.

Comment: Interestingly the key `=` is not listed in interactive help but it is listed on `man top`.